# Windows clustering in Azure VM (Windows 2012 R2)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, azure-vm

I am going through [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-tutorial) to build a SQL Server Always On cluster.  I read through [this page](https://blog.coeo.com/why-do-i-need-a-load-balancer?success=true)  to understand why we need a load balancer in Azure for the listener to work.

That brings me to this section of the Microsoft document which requires us to run a PowerShell script. The parameter I am interested in knowing is the ProbePort.

```
Get-ClusterResource $IPResourceName | Set-ClusterParameter -Multiple @{"Address"="$ClusterCoreIP";"ProbePort"=$ClusterProbePort;"SubnetMask"="255.255.255.255";"Network"="$ClusterNetworkName";"EnableDhcp"=0}
```

When I look at ProbePort on on-prem Always On cluster, it is set to 0. So my question is did the IP address resource always have this parameter/feature associated with it, or did Microsoft introduce it in one of the updates to cater for the Azure Load balancer situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when the probe port feature was introduced, or into which Windows versions, but it's not needed or used on-prem as the cluster nodes can bring the floating IP address online directly.